# Batch file folder copy automatically

Tags: batch-file

Hello everyone :) I have the following issue to solve. : I need to copy a folder automatic within the files after running always refreshing. I would like to do this once every week (every wednesday for example), and i need to copy the files into a folder that name is the current date. My idea is the following: create a batch file with the copy command, and folder creation and take it into the task scheduler.

**Batch file code:**

```
d:
cd testfolder
SET datefolder="%date%
mkdir %datefolder%
xcopy "d:\folder\from copy" "d:\folder\to copy" /E /H /C /R /Q /Y
```

*This code will generate a folder with the current date*. (2016. 11. 25) with spaces.

**The problem is that i don't know how to add to the path the changing folder name.**

Something like this (this doesn't work!)

```
xcopy "d:\folder\from copy" "d:\folder\to copy\%datefolder%" /E /H /C /R /Q /Y
```

Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET "datefolder=%date%"
mkdir "%datefolder%"
xcopy "d:\folder\from copy" "d:\folder\to copy\%datefolder%\" /E /H /C /R /Q /Y
```

The `set "var=value" syntax prevents unwanted trailing spaces being included in the value assigned. The value stored will not contain quotes. In this way, quoting can be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems. You didn't specify the error message you get, but it looks like it's because of the single quote in your `set` command. You put it into your `xcopy` command, and then you have a parameter with 3 quotes (one unmatching) and that doesn't work.

You could simply put %date% into the xcopy command; there's no reason to set it to %datefolder%. Except then you will create subfolders according to the date format. For me, `echo %date%` gives "ddd MM/dd/yyyy" which means that I end up with a dd subfolder and another subfolder yyyy. It works with the xcopy command, but it's not exactly what you asked for.

If that's not good enough, you'll have to create the datefolder format in one of two ways. You can parse `%date%` and use substring extraction (see `help set`) or tokens (see `help for`), or you can make a powershell call.

Example 1:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do set datefolder=%%d. %%b. %%c
```

Example 2:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy. MM. dd')"') do set datefolder=%%a
```

Edit: You'll also want to terminate your destination folder with a `\` so that xcopy knows it's a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast answers :)

Yes, thats right this version doesn't work:

```
SET "datefolder=%date%"
mkdir "%datefolder%"
xcopy "d:\folder\from copy" "d:\folder\to copy\%datefolder%\" /E /H /C /R /Q /Y
```

But this works :

```
echo
d:
cd testfolder
SET datefolder="%date%"
mkdir %datefolder%

xcopy d:\folder\from copy d:\folder\to copy\%datefolder% /E /H /C /R /Q /Y
```

I need to specify the date in a variable, other way not works for me. (creates 3 folders with year month and day) After all the " " signs were the problems in the xcopy command thanks :)